# How to remove trailing spaces in write.table in R

Tags: r, file-io

I have a lagre data frame which looks similar to this format:

```
line1
line2<tab>value1
```

When it is read in R using read.csv it is forced into a data frame as follows:

```
V1<tab>V2
line1<tab>NA
line2<tab>value1
```

I can replace the NA with an empty string, but when I write using write.table, I get a tab and empty space after line 1 in the output file.

How do I make it so that the output is in the same format as the input i.e. the trailing tabbed white space be removed

Sample file appended:

```
#Sample SGA file format
@HD VN:1.0.0    IA:NA
@PL NM:TEST
1   1   705 50947   YDL185W YOR202W -   -   -
1   2   377 50947   YDL185W YOR202W -   -   -
1   3   317 50947   YDL185W YOR202W -   -   -
...
@SP CF:ORF,IGNA
TEST    1
TEST2   1
```

head(dput(data))

```
structure(list(V1 = c("#Sample SGA file format", "@HD", 
"@PL", "1", "1", "1"), V2 = c("", "VN:1.0.0", "NM:TEST", "1", 
"2", "3"), V3 = c("", "IA:NA", "", "705", "377", "317"), V4 = c(NA, 
NA, NA, 50947L, 50947L, 50947L), V5 = c("", "", "", "YDL185W", 
"YDL185W", "YDL185W"), V6 = c("", "", "", "YOR202W", "YOR202W", 
"YOR202W"), V7 = c("", "", "", "-", "-", "-"), V8 = c("", "", 
"", "-", "-", "-"), V9 = c("", "", "", "-", "-", "-")), .Names = c("V1", 
"V2", "V3", "V4", "V5", "V6", "V7", "V8", "V9"), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

and str(data)

```
'data.frame':   1541 obs. of  9 variables:
 $ V1: chr  "#Sample SGA file format" "@HD" "@PL" "1" ...
 $ V2: chr  "" "VN:1.0.0" "NM:TEST" "1" ...
 $ V3: chr  "" "IA:NA" "" "705" ...
 $ V4: int  NA NA NA 50947 50947 50947 50947 50947 50947 50947 ...
 $ V5: chr  "" "" "" "YDL185W" ...
 $ V6: chr  "" "" "" "YOR202W" ...
 $ V7: chr  "" "" "" "-" ...
 $ V8: chr  "" "" "" "-" ...
 $ V9: chr  "" "" "" "-" ...
```

Comment: can you `dput(yourdata)` or a portion of it here.  It sounds like part of the confusion is `NA` vs blank.  There is no blank for numerics in R.  Instead it is represented by NA.  If you force `NA` to be the blank string, the whole column will convert to character.  But I won't know for sure without seeing your data once its read into R.  You can also look at the data with `str(yourdata)`

Comment: Why are you storing your data in a data frame? It seems that it is not a data frame (i.e. a table), so maybe you could just store it in a list.

Comment: @Justin I have appended some data.
GaborCsardi My data has 2 data frames embedded in it so I extract the data frames, process them and put them back in when I'm done with it.

Comment: Please use `dput(yourdata)` or `dput(head(yourdata))` so we can see its structure once its in R.  Also you could show us the output of `str(yourdata)` and the complete code from an empty workspace until you have the data loaded.  Otherwise, it is still very hard to debug what you've shown  us.

Comment: @Justin there you go. The code that loads the data is not trivial. It begins with a read.csv and the rest is extraction of the data frames using the header tags '@' , validation of columns/data. This is a part of a really large pipeline, other than the read.csv, theres not much that would be informative to you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll wager a guess.  It sounds like you could do one of two things.

First, you could use

```
data[is.na(data)] <- ''
library(stringr)
write.table(str_trim(apply(data, 1, paste, collapse='\t')),
            'fileout.tsv',
            row.names=FALSE)
```

Or you can use a command line utility like `sed` to remove trailing whitespace from a file:

```
sed -e :a -e 's/^.\{1,77\}$/ & /;ta'
```

Answer (score 3):

This is very convoluted, but here goes.

1. Read line1 as a header in `read.csv`: `foo <- read.csv("input.csv")`
2. Write just the 1st column name using `write`: `write(colnames(foo)[1],"out/output.csv")`
3. Finally, write the rest of the table using `append`and without column names: `write.table(foo,"output.csv",sep=",",row.names=F,col.names=F,append=T,quote=F)`

This should get you the output file in the same format at the input file.

Comment: Hmm this would work, however, the data I have is much larger. I.e. there are lots of lines like line 1 in the middle.

Answer (score 3):

This is similar to Justin's answer, using regex.

```
cn <- file("output.txt",open="w") #opens write connection to file
writeLines(paste(names(data),collapse="\t"),con=cn) #writes header
#converts data frame into vector of character, with fields separated by tabs
to.print <- apply(data,1,paste,collapse="\t") 
to.print <- gsub("\\tNA$","",to.print) #deletes trailing <tab>NA
writeLines(to.print,con=cn) #writes data frame rows
close(cn)
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want `read.table` to behave exactly as `read.csv` does, all you need to do is make the parameters the same

```
read.table(file, header = TRUE, sep = ",", quote="\"", dec=".",
     fill = TRUE, comment.char="")
```