# How to remove trailing blanks or linebreaks from CSV file created with write.table?

Tags: r, csv

I want to write a data frame from R into a CSV file. Consider the following toy example

```
df <- data.frame(ID = c(1,2,3), X = c("a", "b", "c"), Y = c(1,2,NA))
df[which(is.na(df[,"Y"])), 1]

write.table(t(df), file = "path to CSV/test.csv", sep = ""), col.names=F, sep=",", quote=F)
```

The output in `test.csv`looks as follows

```
ID,1,2,3
X,a,b,c
Y, 1, 2,NA
```

At first glance, this is exactly as I need it, BUT what cannot be seen in the code insertion above is that after the `NA` in the last line, there is another linebreak. When I pass `test.csv` to a Javascript chart on a website, however, the trailing linebreak causes trouble.

Is there a way to avoid this final linebreak within R?

Comment: I think there's an extra ) in your write.table statement, ans also an extra sep=; not that it matters. I just noticed while trying to validate the stringr solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a little convoluted, but obtains your desired result:

```
zz <- textConnection("foo", "w")
write.table(t(df), file = zz, col.names=F, sep=",", quote=F)
close(zz)
foo
# [1] "ID,1,2,3"   "X,a,b,c"    "Y, 1, 2,NA"
cat(paste(foo, collapse='\n'), file = 'test.csv', sep='')
```

You should end up with a file that has newline character after only the first two data rows.

Comment: Yup @Thomas, this works! Thanks for the immediate help.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a command line utility like sed to remove trailing whitespace from a file:

`sed -e :a -e 's/^.\{1,77\}$/ & /;ta'`

Or, you could begin by writing a single row then using `append`.

Comment: Thx @NerdLife, but the solution with `stringr` still produces a linebreak at the end.

Comment: @pfifas You're welcome. It does? I apologize, I will remove it after verifying this later today then. I forked it from another StackOverflow post that said that it fixes this problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12185889/how-to-remove-trailing-spaces-in-write-table-in-r

Comment: Yep, you're right. Sorry for the bogus solution; I'll remove it now. It looks like it should work, I'm sure it just needs a minor tweak but you've got a solution so I'll just remove it. One last thing -- FYI a lot of times trailing whitespace can be caused by the types of carriage returns being used.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative in the similar vein of the answer by @Thomas, but with slightly less typing. Send output from `write.csv` to a character string (`capture.out`). Concatenate the string (`paste`) and separate the elements with linebreaks (`collapse = \n`). Write to file with `cat`.

```
x <- capture.output(write.csv(df, row.names = FALSE, quote = FALSE))
cat(paste(x, collapse = "\n"), file = "df.csv")
```

---

You may also use `format_csv` from package `readr` to create a character vector with line breaks (`\n`). Remove the last end-of-line `\n` with `substr`. Write to file with `cat`.

```
library(readr)
x <- format_csv(df)
cat(substr(x, 1, nchar(x) - 1), file = "df.csv")
```